# Get stringvalue of NSTextField within a NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I would like to know how I can get the stringvalue of a textfield thats in a NSCollectionView. The textfield is created with a prototype for the collectionview.

I dont know if I should use `representedObject` or something else and how.

Answer (score 0):

In the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method set the textfield tag to be the indexPath row.

Then set the textfield delegate to be your controller or any other desired object.

On "textFieldDidEndEditing" method from UITextFieldDelegate protocol check the tag from the textfield so you know which index was modified.

GL HF

Comment: So first, I dont have the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method. And is there a way I could receive the textfields stringvalue with the label thats in the same view (prototype view) of all rows?